# Missing logout page in view/users in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller

I am working on cakephp and while clicking on logout button url goes to some other address http://demo4sbc.com.Because there is no logout.ctp present in view/users, so can any one tell me the coding for logout.ctp page.

Comment: please post the code of your logout() action in usersController

Comment: Did you create any logout method in UsersController ?

Comment: function logout() 
 {
  $this->Session->destroy();
  $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
 }
 public function google_logout(){
  $this->Session->destroy();
  
  $this->Session->delete('Glogin');

header('Location: https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout?continue=https://appengine.google.com/_ah/logout?continue=http://yesstays.com/');
$this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
 
 }

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need `logout.ctp` view, just check where you redirect users after logout

how about this:

**UsersController.php**

```
public function logout() {

    $this->Session->destroy();

    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

**AppController.php**

```
class AppController extends Controller
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array('fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'))
            ),
            //Controller and Action where you want redirect users after login
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'Users',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            //Controller and Action where you want redirect users after logout
            'logoutRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'Pages', 
                'action' => 'home', 
            ),
        ));

    }
```

Comment: thank you very much i got my error,and now if i had some data in database and on search the result is blank page...why